# Trying to use Django-Leaflet - only see blank screen

Tags: django, leaflet

I followed the instructions [here](https://github.com/makinacorpus/django-leaflet#usage), up to adding the map to my template, resulting in the following:

example.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load leaflet_tags %}
<head>


 {% leaflet_js %}
    {% leaflet_css %}
</head>

  <body style="height:100%; width:100%;">
    {% leaflet_map "yourmap" %}
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

I installed Django-Leaflet without problems using pip.  I also added the app to my installed apps and included Leaflet settings.

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    #
    'leaflet',
]

LEAFLET_CONFIG = {
'DEFAULT_CENTER': (52.00,20.00),
'DEFAULT_ZOOM': 6,
'MIN_ZOOM': 1,
'MAX_ZOOM': 20,
}
```

When I look in firebug, I see that the template tags have successfully loaded the leaflet js and css files, as well as created a "map" div in the body.  However, the map does not include any leaflet attributes besides css/height.

What could be going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You have to give a height to the div you are assigning your map to. In your case just create a CSS rule for the 'yourmap' div giving it a height.